# iOS UIdocumentpicker: APK file is showing grey

Tags: ios, iphone, uidocumentpickervc

I am trying to integrate UIPickerViewController to pick apk file but it is showing grey.

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController* docPicker =
[[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.data"]
                                                       inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
```

Here is [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmtax.png)

Comment: Don't paste the screenshots of the code. Paste code. Your question is more likely to attract down votes

Comment: sorry , Just updated code